# How to get a list of all the MS SQL Server instances on the local machine?

Tags: sql-server

This seems to be a fairly common question, but none of the answers I've seen have been particularly satisfactory. I want to get a list of the names of the MS SQL Server instances installed on the local machine, regardless of whether they're started or not. For the purposes of this discussion, I'm OK with just finding instances of SQL 2005 and newer; I can handle 2000 and earlier using "legacy" methods (i.e., look in the registry). What I do require is that it not be dependent on the SQL Server Browser service (it's disabled by default nowadays), and that 64-bit instances are returned even when the app is 32-bit.

Suggestions I've seen:

- Dig through the registry: Supposedly [Not recommended](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2006/07/29/682254.aspx) due to the registry entries being undocumented; MS may change them in the future. More importantly, as far as I can tell, 64-bit instances of MSSQL go in the 64-bit HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server InstalledInstances, and 32-bit instances go in the 32-bit one, so a 32-bit app won't see any 64-bit instances.
- Use the [SQL WMI Provider for Configuration Management](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2006/07/29/682254.aspx) mentioned in the previous blog post. This seems to be the closest, but despite the author's admonition to avoid using the registry because it might change, it turns out the WMI namespace changed between SQL 2005 and 2008: in 2005, it's root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ComputerManagement, but in 2008 it's root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ComputerManagement10. Will it change again in the future? That said, it's probably not a huge issue if I have to update my app for a future version of SQL.

  The problem I have with the WMI method is that the SqlService class returns a list of the service names, whereas I want the *instance* names. E.g., instead of MSSQL$INSTANCE, I just want INSTANCE. Stripping off the "MSSQL$" is trivial, as is handling the special case of the default instance, but is it reliable? AFAIK, there's technically no reason why the service couldn't be renamed, while keeping the instance name the same. That said, unless someone has a better method, I think I'll go with that (get the service names and strip off the MSSQL$). The ServerSettings class returns the instance name, but it doesn't see a 64-bit instance of SQL 2008 R2 Express that I have installed on my machine.
- Use `SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers(true)`: this seems to depend on the SQL Server Browser service. It works great if the Browser service is started, but if it's not, I just get a single row with the computer name as the server name and a blank instance name.
- Use `System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator.GetDataSources()`: same problem that it depends on the SQL Server Browser.

So, are there some other methods that might work better?

Comment: be aware that on Windows Server 2012 and on Windows 8, using WMI to detect instances of SQL Server 2008 R2 may fail if it is not updated to the Service Pack 2 (SQL Server 2008 R2 10.50.4000, Service Pack 2). It fails in module svrenumapi100.dll, used by wmiprvse.exe

Answer (score 14):

I am able to see both 2005 and 2008 SQL Server instances on my laptop using Powershell:

```
Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Name -like 'MSSQL$*'}
```

Other possibilities to explore include enumerating through the [RegisteredServers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ambujnautiyal/archive/2009/02/15/enumerating-sql-server-2k8-and-2k5-registered-servers-from-smo-10.aspx) namespace.

Comment: Hmm, is that reliable? That is, is it guaranteed that MSSQL's DisplayName will always start with "SQL Server ("? I'm thinking about localized versions--the only non-English version I have installed is French, and it's OK there. However, since some other SQL-related service DisplayNames _are_ localized (e.g., "SQL Server Agent (INSTANCE)" is "Agent SQL Server (INSTANCE)" in French), I'm not convinced that there's not some language where MSSQL's DisplayName doesn't start with "SQL Server (". Seems like looking for a service name that starts with "MSSQL$" is more reliable than this method.

Comment: It's a fair question. I adjusted the answer to only search for Name like 'MSSQL$*' (which also returns correct results on my computer) although I'm not sure how it will appear on different region settings.

Comment: Doesn't work for the default instance which is called `MSSQLSERVER` (i.e. not starting with `MSSQL$`).

Answer (score 6):

From a command prompt (cmd.exe):

```
sc query|findstr "DISPLAY_NAME"|findstr /C:"SQL Server (" > myfile.txt

FOR /F " tokens=2 delims=()" %i in (myfile.txt) do @echo %computername%\%i
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an older post, but I did come to this post today looking for a way to find installed instances of SQL Server.  Although the two answers given are helpful, I think they only pertain to installed and **running** instances of SQL Server.  If SQL Server Configuration Manager is installed, all installed instances should be listed under the SQL Server Services node.  Here you might find an instance that is installed, but not running.  You can right click the instance and start it.  I am sure there are other ways to do this; it is just a way that came in handy for me today and I thought I would share it.

Comment: running Windows Services and finding SQL Server services is an alternative if you don't have the Configuration Manager installed

Answer (score 3):

The *SQL Browser service* (if active) speaks [SSRP/MS-SQLR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc219709.aspx) on UDP Port 1434.

It is the component which is used for remote discovery of instances (and also determining their port). It helps also discovery in a network.

It is however disabled by default (good thing for surface reduction).

Comment: I have inspected UDP packet sent by SqlDataSourceEnumerator (with Wireshark). Sent `02` to UDP `255.255.255.255:1434`. Received `05 xx yy <serverList>`. The serverList is `server;;server;;...`. The server is `ServerName;SERVER;InstanceName;BEXEC;IsClustered;No;Version;11.0.2100.60`

Answer (score 2):

This might be helpful , i have tried this in Sql Server 2008 :

```
select * from sys.servers
```

Comment: That shows the list of database servers linked to the server that you executed that query on. Some of the linked servers might be on other computers, or they might not be even be MSSQL (you can link to an ODBC data source, or an Access database, etc...). Also, it's not going to show other MSSQL instances that are on the same machine, unless someone has explicitly linked them. The question is about how to get the list of the installed MSSQL instances, so requiring that you already know of an instance, and also have the credentials to connect to it, isn't going to work.