# Find all SQL Server databases in an Instance using Java

Tags: java, sql-server

How can I list all SQL Server databases within a known instance on my machine?

Comment: similar thread, not Java specific, but it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570738/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-the-ms-sql-server-instances-on-the-local-machine

Comment: Thanks for the link but it is reffering to listing the SQL Server instances. Certainly a good start, but I need to list the SQL Server databases (assume I know the SQL Server instance).

Comment: Ahh OK, they maybe you want to execute the following query: `SELECT name, database_id, create_date
FROM sys.databases `  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188613.aspx

Comment: I clarified your question based on the comments you posted to other users here.

Answer (score 3):

You can try with `DatabaseMetaData#getCatalog()` from JDBC (works with MS SQLServerDriver and jTDS driver):

```
import java.sql.*;
public class ListDatabases
{
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    Connection con = null;
    try {
       Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
       con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1269;"
               + "user=sa;password=HerongYang");

       DatabaseMetaData meta = con.getMetaData();
       ResultSet res = meta.getCatalogs();
       System.out.println("List of databases: "); 
       while (res.next()) {
          System.out.println(res.getString("TABLE_CAT"));
       }
       res.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
       System.err.println("Exception: " + e);
    } finally {
       con.close();
    }
  }
}
```