# How to get list of SQL Servers 2016 on local machine ( in the most correct way )?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

Unfortunately old ways listed in this topic [How to get a list of all the SQL Server instances on the local machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570738/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-the-ms-sql-server-instances-on-the-local-machine) seems to now working for new versions of SQL Servers which I have.

I have SQL Server 2016.

I can get that server list from register but I don't think I can call it "Correct way".

So the question is what is most correct way to get that list?

Thank You for all suggestions!