# SQL Server instance discovery using SqlServer PowerShell module

Tags: sql-server, powershell, dbatools

The dbatools module's `Find-DbaInstance` can accept a computer name and return a list of instances on that machine. Is there an equivalent in the SqlServer module that does this? I tried `Get-SqlInstance`, but it seems to need actual instance names, as opposed to being able to use it for instance discovery. I'd prefer to use dbatools, but the SqlServer module is what I have consistent access to in the current environment.

Comment: Which type of scan do you want: WMI or SQL Browser or a specific TCP port or SPN lookup?

Comment: @Charlieface, WMI seems like it would be the most reliable (Browser might be disabled, the port *may* be something other than 1433, etc.). I am attempting to find every last 'rogue' install of SQL Server as those unknown instances are the most vulnerable (you can't patch them or retire them if you don't even know they exist).

Comment: Not sure about WMI, maybe look through the code https://github.com/dataplat/dbatools/blob/development/functions/Get-DbaService.ps1 Is there any reason you don't want to install DBA Tools, it's pretty easy

Comment: Using dbatools is the ultimate goal, but the rollout is only partially complete and our security software (after an upgrade) has suddenly started labeling dbatools as 'potentially malicious' and blocks it from running, so until that's remedied, it's not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many good results that dont even depend on the sqlserver module in [this article](https://www.sqlshack.com/six-methods-to-automatically-discover-sql-server-instances/)

eg.

```
$SQLInstances = Invoke-Command -ComputerName "localhost" {
    (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server').InstalledInstances
}

foreach ($sql in $SQLInstances) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ServerName = $sql.PSComputerName
        InstanceName = $sql
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570738/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-the-ms-sql-server-instances-on-the-local-machine), I have avoided the method you suggest. I am trying to find every last 'rogue' install of SQL Server as those unknown instances are the most vulnerable (you can't patch them or retire them if you don't even know they exist).

Comment: Have a look at the section labelled `Get-Service cmdlet` in the link I mentioned, that uses WMI to some extent, happy to edit my answer if that is your preferred method?

Comment: I worked through the different methods mentioned in the article. I was surprised at how well using `Get-ChildItem` addressed this problem and a couple of others I've been dealing with. For what I'm doing, It's even better than SMO.